# Fwupdmgr reports that update was done "not correctly" but the firmware seems to have updated succesfully

Tags: thinkpad, bios, fwupd

Has anyone experienced the following from fwupdmgr?

Basically, I used it to do a few updates.

```
fwupdmgr update
```

Everything seems successful and the version has changed in the BIOS. But after the reboot when I do:

```
fwupdmgr get-devices
```

It gives a warning:

```
Devices that were not updated correctly:
System Firmware (0.1.30 → 0.1.31)
```

and proceeds to upload an error report.

Also, fwupdmgr does report that the firmware version is now 0.1.31. Should I be worried about it or the warning is just a bug?

My laptop is thinkpad T14s AMD gen 3, running Ubuntu 22.04.

max